# StrutsTestCase for struts 2.2.x

Tags: java, web, struts2, junit

Latest version of StrutsTestCase (2.1.4-1.2-2.4) has dependency on org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet class and this [seems to be deprecated](http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet) class in latest versions of Struts.

Is StrutsTestCase deprecated project ? does not support for Struts 2.2.X ?

If it is not supported for latest version of struts, is there anyother alternative to test (junit) struts action classes?

Comment: [Struts2-JUnit-Plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts-2-junit-plugin-tutorial.html) and [Testing Actions](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/testing-actions.html)

Comment: I'm confused; where's the dependency in S2 on S1 (execept for the S1 plugin, of course)?

Comment: This is an old [project](http://strutstestcase.sourceforge.net), I've used it 6 years ago. Seems dead.

Comment: You can also just call the setters on your action and then the execute method. You don't actually need a plugin.